# corrupt tar.gz archive

Tags: tar, data-recovery, gunzip

I'm new here and I want to ask something maybe you can help me. I wanted to service my NAS and I had to download all the data that I had on it, so what I did is downloaded whole data trough webbrowser and saved as sharedfolders.tar.gz size 1,1TB. Now i want to extract some of the data thats in this file because I don't need whole data ( I should downloaded only the needed data but laziness had me :S) I have windows PC also MacBook Pro with the newest OS Catalina. I tride BetterZip app for Mac but shows only 16GB Data and file size is showed 1,1TB. I tried Terminal.app with tar to extract whole data, it starts everything is fine but then comes to one file (SIMS3.zip file) and says tar damaged. and cant do anything. Any help or answer will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you run `gzip -dc sharedfolders.tar.gz > sharedfolders.tar` in a terminal? This should create an uncompressed copy. Or try `gzip -t sharedfolders.tar.gz` to test the compressed file integrity.

Comment: I will try now to uncompress it and after that extract it. It will take a while. I will bring the results as long as I have them.

Comment: I extract it to .tar format and tried with integrated mac os archive extractor to extract it but no luck. Was an error shown I didn't get it and turned off the laptop. I will try to extract the sharedfolders.tar with Terminal.app using tar command and I will update you what is going on.

Comment: Please [edit] your question write all additional information there. Did you check that uncompressing the file did not show any error? You might have an incomplete file if there was an error in the compressed data.